# How to get the real time while opening and closing the file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, if-statement

I need real time while opening and closing the file.
I have used this:

```
#####
file1 = open("file.txt",mode="r+")
file1.close()
if (file1.close()==True):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

but it is not showing the output.

Answer (score 0):

you call twice file1.close, only the first one <strike>returns True</strike> !

Comment: the `close` method doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

It does not print the time or date because `file1.close()` does not return any value, so the `if` statement doesn't get executed.
`file1.close()` just closes the file handle. You can instead print the time just before closing the file like this:

```
import datetime

file1 = open("file.txt", "r+")
print(datetime.datetime.now())
file1.close()
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you need to get the difference in time between opening and closing the file, then call `datetime.now` before and after, store it in two variables and subtract them, like so:

```
import datetime

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
file1 = open("file.txt", "r+")
# other operations here
file1.close()
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
t = t2 - t1
print (t)
```

This might print something like **0:00:0.000114**, which is in the format

> minutes:seconds:microseconds

So, it takes 114 microseconds here.

Comment: i need the differences between opening time and closing time of a file.

Comment: @BikashBehera okay, I have modified to answer that, check it out

Answer (score 0):

`file.close()` returns `None` in most cases, so the condition in the `if` statement will not be `True` and the timestamp will not be printed.

If you know that the file will not be explicitly closed you could open the file with a context manager.

```
from datetime import datetime

with open("file.txt", mode="r+") as file1:
    opened = datetime.now()
    # do stuff with file

duration = datetime.now() - opened

print('File opened for {}'.format(duration.total_seconds()))
```

When the context manager is exited the file will be automatically closed, and you can use that instant as the approximate close time.